# Order of `\thanks`, `\footnote` and AAAI copyright notice

Tags: footnotes

The order of `\thanks`, `\footnote` and AAAI copyright notice is pretty strange: AAAI copyright notice is in the middle of `\thanks` and `\footnote`. How can I solve it by pushing AAAI copyright notice down to the bottom, or up to the footnote line?

An example:

```
\def\year{2017}\relax
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{aaai17}  %Required
\usepackage{times}  %Required
\usepackage{helvet}  %Required
\usepackage{courier}  %Required
\usepackage{url}  %Required
\usepackage{graphicx}  %Required
\frenchspacing  %Required
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}  %Required
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}  %Required

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\title{My title\thanks{Thanks}}
\author{}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some texts with footnotes\footnote{Footnote}.

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: The `.sty` file found [here](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet-5.5-paper/blob/master/aaai17.sty) clearly states modifications to the style will result in rejection of your paper for AAAI publication. Is this written for that purpose, or not? If it is the former, I doubt we'll be able to help? If it is the latter, the `.sty` file states we will be able to modify it but to leave appropriate credits and to change the name to not include `aaai`. Please advise.

Comment: @Troy No, the sty file shouldn't be modified at least for my case. But I wonder whether it is possible to make this change without modifying the sty file.

Comment: It also states modifications to your source file (which I interpret as your .tex file) is not allowed, if it is meant for publication. So is it for publication, or not? And yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Troy Yes, this is meant for publication. But is swapping the copyright notice to the bottom considered modification to the style sheet? If so, do you have any other suggestions to avoid this ugliness?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. You would have to check with AAAI for that. I can write up an answer using `\renewcommand` first. If someone with more experience in this matter recognizes it as a violation of some sort then I'll take the answer down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `aaai17.sty` referenced in this answer was taken from [Github](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet-5.5-paper/blob/master/aaai17.sty). If there are any issues with copyright etc., let me know and I will take the answer down. Quoted verbatim from the `.sty` file (all credits to authors of the sty file):
>
> ```
> % WARNING: IF YOU ARE USING THIS STYLE SHEET FOR AN AAAI PUBLICATION, YOU
> % MAY NOT MODIFY IT FOR ANY REASON. MODIFICATIONS (IN YOUR SOURCE 
> % OR IN THIS STYLE SHEET WILL RESULT IN REJECTION OF YOUR PAPER).
> %
> % NOTICE: DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE WITHOUT CHANGING ITS NAME. 
> % This style file is called aaai17.sty. Modifications to this file are permitted,
> % provided that your modified version does not include the acronym "aaai"
> % in its name, that credit to the authors and supporting agencies is
> % retained, and that further modification or reuse is not restricted.
> ```

The issue here is that the copyright line is printed during `\maketitle`, which is why it appears after your `\thanks` and before `\footnote`. My approach here is to use `\renewcommand` to turn off printing of the copyright line during `\maketitle` and to add it in at the end of the document.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{aaai17}  %Required
\usepackage{times}  %Required
\usepackage{helvet}  %Required
\usepackage{courier}  %Required
\usepackage{url}  %Required
\usepackage{graphicx}  %Required
\frenchspacing  %Required
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}  %Required
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}  %Required

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\title{My title\thanks{Thanks}}
\makeatletter% <-------------------
    \renewcommand{\copyright@on}{F}
    \AtEndDocument{%
        \insert\footins{\noindent\footnotesize\copyright@text}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    Some texts with footnotes\footnote{Footnote}.
\end{document}
```

[image: pic]

I note here that you should probably check with AAAI if you intend to use this for publication, as the instructions in the style file clearly states *no modifications to the source file* is allowed.