# Footnote text without numbers before `\thanks`

Tags: footnotes, koma-script

I need to set some copyright text before the `thanks` note. The answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368989/order-of-thanks-footnote-and-aaai-copyright-notice) has a similar solution, but for a specific package -- and I need to insert the note/colophon *before* the first `thanks`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\title{A title}
\author{John Doe\thanks{Thank you all, I need some text above this.}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, do please tell us *where* the note/colophon is supposed to go. E.g., does it come before the `\title` directive?

Comment: @Mico, it should be a "footnote", but without any mark, just like  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368989/order-of-thanks-footnote-and-aaai-copyright-notice). As to where I can insert it in the document to make it appear like that, it doesn't matter, but it would be nice if I could use it like `\thanks` (inside `title` or `author`)

Comment: I had suggested a hackish alternative on top of the answer that has been deleted, which should work under your requirements. Would a "not so clean" solution be welcome?

Comment: @gusbrs, of course it would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an elegant way do do things (not recommended either), and I'm only giving this as an answer because the OP explicitly manifested to be open to a hackish solution, as long as the requirements were satisfied. Someone might well come up with something better.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\copyrightnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{\kern-5pt \textcolor{white}{\rule{5pt}{2ex}}#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\title{A title}
\author{John Doe\copyrightnote{My copyright note.}\thanks{Thank you all, I need some text above this.}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]